# How to automatically load an image inside the post, since it is present in uploads folder

Tags: images, title

I´d like to automatically load three images inside all posts (via single.php), always in the same div (.acf_imgs-centro1). The idea is that the images are uploaded into uploads folder, with the same name as the post, and then they will be displayed inside the post. I can do it using the code bellow, but there is a problem... I have a static title (.imgs_h2) above the images divs, and I want it (the title) to load only since there are any image loaded. I can, for example, have the post and not yet have the image in the folder, so the title will be invisible. No Image, no title. Right now, the method i´m using seems incompatible with what I want to achiev. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="acf_imgs-centro1">
          <h2 class="imgs_h2">Compartilhe nas redes sociais</h2>
          <div class="img-neutra">
             <img alt="Significado de <?php the_title(); ?>" src="http://teste.significadodosnomes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/nomes-unisex/<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>.jpg" onerror="this.style.opacity='0'" >
             </div>
          <div class="img-fem">
             <img alt="Significado de <?php the_title(); ?>" src="http://teste.significadodosnomes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/nomes-femininos/<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>.jpg" onerror="this.style.opacity='0'"></div>
          <div class="img-masc">
             <img alt="Significado de <?php the_title(); ?>" src="http://teste.significadodosnomes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/nomes-masculinos/<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>.jpg" onerror="this.style.opacity='0'" ></div>

              </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if those files exist before you output that div. You can clean up your markup and get rid of that `onerror` call by wrapping each image div in a `file_exists` check.  Use a ternary to check if the file exists and set the `$image` variable if it is.  Like so:

```
$image1 = "/nomes-unisex/" . $post->post_name . ".jpg";
$image2 = "/nomes-femininos/" . $post->post_name . ".jpg";
$image3 = "/nomes-masculinos/" . $post->post_name . ".jpg";
$uploadDir = wp_get_upload_dir();

$image1 = file_exists($uploadDir['basedir'] . $image1) ? $uploadDir['baseurl'] . $image1 : '';
$image2 = file_exists($uploadDir['basedir'] . $image2) ? $uploadDir['baseurl'] . $image2 : '';
$image3 = file_exists($uploadDir['basedir'] . $image3) ? $uploadDir['baseurl'] . $image3 : '';
?>
<div class="acf_imgs-centro1">
<?php if ($image1 || $image2 || $image3) {
    ?>
    <h2 class="imgs_h2">Compartilhe nas redes sociais</h2>
    <?php if ($image1) { ?>
        <div class="img-neutra">
            <img alt="Significado de <?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $image1; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php }
    if ($image2) { ?>
        <div class="img-fem">
            <img alt="Significado de <?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $image2; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php }
    if ($image3) { ?>
        <div class="img-masc">
            <img alt="Significado de <?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $image3; ?>">
        </div>
    <?php }
} ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi mrben522. Thank´s for your answer.
Don´t know why, but images are not loading.
I placed images into each separate folder, tested urls and images are there.

Comment: Image of how the code is inserted in my single.php is placed above.

Comment: Oh that's my fault.  `file_exists` is expecting a path, not a url.  I'll update that answer for you

Comment: Bro, still not working.

Comment: I'm not in your system so I can't be sure what the issue is.  Try and `var_dump` out different parts of that logic to see what it's breaking on.

Comment: add `var_dump(file_exists($uploadDir['basedir'] . $image1));` after line 4.

Comment: in your code or in hamdirizal´s?
inserting that line in he´s code, gives "bool(false)"

Comment: Ok mrben522, your code works now.
Only have to get rid of "bool(true)", but thats ok.

Comment: remove the `var_dump` line to get rid of that

Answer (score 0):

Just check the if the file exists first before showing the DIV.

```
<?php 
$image_1 = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/nomes-unisex/' . $post->post_name . 'jpg';
$image_2 = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/nomes-femininos/' . $post->post_name . 'jpg';
$image_3 = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/nomes-masculinos/' . $post->post_name . 'jpg';
if(file_exists($image_1) && file_exists($image_2) && file_exists($image_3)):
?>
<div class="acf_imgs-centro1">
    <h2>your code</h2>
    <div>your code</div>
    <div>your code</div>
    <div>your code</div>
</div><!-- .acf_imgs-centro1 -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: man, sorry, but I´m not a PHP coder.
What goes into <div>your code</div>???

Comment: Your original code. You may replace line 7 to 12 with your original code that you've posted in the question.

Comment: Sorry... not working either.
See second image please.

Comment: Below the $imag_3 line, do this `var_dump(file_exists($image_1));die()` And see the results. If it says `null` or `false` then it means that your image file doesn't exists. If it says `true`, then check the next image file. Do that until you find the problem.